# Example for uncorrelated but not independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, correlation

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and define
$$
Y =
\begin{cases} 
X, &\mbox{if } |X| \leq c, \\
-X, & \mbox{if } |X| > c .
\end{cases}
$$
The article [Normally distributed and uncorrelated does not imply independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#An_asymmetric_example) says that it is possible to choose $c > 0$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. How can I find this constant $c$?

Comment: How? By computing $E(X)$, $E(Y)$ and $E(XY)$. Which ones are a problem?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2 \mathbb{I}_\left\{|X| \le c\right\}\right]
 = \int_{x=-c}^{x=c} x^2 \phi(x)dx,
$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the pdf of the standard normal.

You can do the same to the other integral and find $c$ numerically.

Comment: There is actually an specific solution, namely the square root of the median of a $\chi^2$ random variable with $3$ degrees of freedom, which can be found manipulating your expression and using the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: @Henry agreed, clever

Comment: Steffen Lauritzen gave it in some [lecture examples in 2008](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/bs2HT9/siss3.pdf). It would be nice to have an intuitive explanation

Comment: @Henry in your notes, he gives all the details, just trying to force $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$. It's just a clever substitution trick

Comment: Yes - there is a difficult integral and he spots that with the substitution the integrand is related to the density function of $\chi^2_3$.  But is it possible to give an explanation which is is not based on the exponents in the integral?

Comment: @Henry I don't know of the intuitive reason why this integral would come out like that

Comment: Alternatively, you can show $c$ is also the solution to $\phi(c) - c\Phi(c)=\frac34$ but again I do see an intuitive reason